# Computing a time span variable in a thread returns weird results

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a background worker and I am doing 3 things.

1. I am calling a callback method until I reach a processed state
2. Updating the progress bar
3. I am computing a time span variable

For operations 1 and 3 I am calling a new thread since they block and I want them computed in parallel. Problem is operation 1 just happens fine.

But operation 3 i.e computing time span returns weird results like -2:-1:-47 and the entire UI keeps shaking. I also tried using a lock but it still doesn't help.

Here is my code when I am starting the background worker. Please see the Thread th2 that's where the problem is.

```
private void StartCurrentRun(bool obj)
{
    this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    StartTimer();

    this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
    this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
    this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

    IsLiveProgress = true;

    this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   CreateEventLogs.WriteToEventLog(string.Format("Run with Assay:{0} Volume{1} has been started", SelectedAssay, SelectedVolume));

   if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
   }

   int OriginalTimeRemaining = SelectedVolumeEstimatedTime(); //This method call returns a result 5.
   int TotalPrecentagebasedOnNumberOfStates = 50;
   int PercentProgress = 100 / TotalPrecentagebasedOnNumberOfStates;
   CurrentCartridgeStatus status = CurrentCartridgeStatus.NotProcessed;
   var instance = ConnectToInstrument.InstrumentConnectionInstance;

   instance.InitalizeRun();

   Thread th = new Thread(() => {
                    do
                    {
                        var result = instance.SubscribeToRunStatusChange(SelectedAssay.display_name, int.Parse(SelectedVolume.Remove(SelectedVolume.Length - 2, 2)));
                        //var result = Test(current);
                        status = result.Result;
                        CurrentStatus = status.ToString();
                        Debug.WriteLine(status.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        CreateEventLogs.WriteToEventLog("Run status - " + CurrentStatus);
                    }
                    while (status != CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed);
                });

   th.Start();

   Thread th2 = new Thread(() =>
          {
              while (status != CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed)
              {
                  lock (_objectForThread2)
                  {
                      OriginalTimeRemaining -= 2;
                      EstimatedTimeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(OriginalTimeRemaining);
                      OnPropertyChanged("EstimatedTimeRemaining");
                  }
              }

          });

    th2.Start();

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PercentProgress; i++)
    {
        for (int j = counter; j <= TotalPrecentagebasedOnNumberOfStates; j++)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(Math.Min(j, 100));

            if (status != CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60);
            }
        }

        counter = 50;
        TotalPrecentagebasedOnNumberOfStates += 50;
    }

    th.Join();
    th2.Join();
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

public void StartTimer()
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += dispatcherTimerTick_;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    timer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimerTick_(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Elapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    TimeElapsed = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
            Elapsed.Hours, Elapsed.Minutes, Elapsed.Seconds);

    OnPropertyChanged("TimeElapsed");
}
```

In the xaml I am binding it like this

```
<StackPanel
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="tblRemainingTime"
        Text="{StaticResource EstimatedTimeRemaining}">
   <Run
            Text=" "></Run>

    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding
                StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}:{2}">
                <Binding
                    Path="EstimatedTimeRemaining.Hours" />
                <Binding
                    Path="EstimatedTimeRemaining.Minutes" />
                <Binding
                    Path="EstimatedTimeRemaining.Seconds" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your thread `th2` will run in a continuous loop at maximum speed, that will rest 2 seconds from `OriginalTimeRemaining` on each iteration and each iteration can take less than microseconds so it's normal you get those values. Aren't you missing a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` on the loop?

Comment: Thanks that helped me fix the issue. Yes I am missing Thread.Sleep.

Comment: As a note, threading timers are the correct tool for what you are doing, no need to span and manage a new thread.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. I will try using a Timer instead of a thread.